# how to hide a range of rows based off of cell value

Tags: vba, range, row, hide

I am trying to auto hide rows that have a zero in K3 to K 17 automatically. I found this code that I have been trying to tamper with to get to work but it seems to always hide every empty cell in the column and not the specific range.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, ""K"").End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
For Each c In Range(""K3:K17"" & LastRow)
If c.Value = 0 Then
    c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf c.Value > 0 Then
    c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
Next
On Error GoTo 0
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub"
```

Comment: Does this even compile with the double double quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have the strings inside single double quotes, you are looping over a lot of lines:

```
For Each c In Range("K3:K17" & LastRow)
```

`LastRow` is the last non-empty row (in column K) so if it is 17 for example, what you are doing is

```
For Each c In Range("K3:K1717")
```

The fix is obvious I hope but here it is anyway

```
For Each c In Range("K3:K17")
```